# Placement of ImageButtons in corners of LinearLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-imagebutton

I am trying to place two `ImageButton` in the corners of a `LinearLayout` as shown in figure below:

[image]

I have tried using the `android:layout_gravity` attribute with the value set to `left` and `right` for the two buttons. However, they show just next to each other as shown in image below:

[image]

How can I place the two image buttons in the corners of the `LinearLayout`? I have looked up a lot of previous answers and tried them but nothing seems to work. How can this placement of image buttons be done?

The XML of the layout is in the snippet below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|fill_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/prev_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:contentDescription="@string/prev_button"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:contentDescription="@string/next_button"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_right"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share your xml?

Comment: @mTak I have shared the XML for the layout.

Comment: Use RelativeLayout as answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/prev_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/prev_button"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/next_button"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_right"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

A relativelayout is better for positioning views at the edges of the screen

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Isn't RelativeLayout expensive than LinearLayout? One such discussion is here- https://medium.com/@vatsalbajpai/android-relative-layout-vs-linear-layout-f27bf3d8f74e. Though my application is pretty simple for now but it is expensive. Is there a better resource where I can learn where and when to use which layout?

Comment: There is another LinearLayout with two Buttons and one TextView.

Comment: A layout with 2 Buttons and 1 TextView and another Layout with 2 Buttons will never be expensive even with the weakest device. The talk about expensive layouts is about more complex layouts.

Comment: Thank you so much @mTak. Is there any resource where I can learn such details better?

Comment: You're in the best source, but it's good to follow others like the link you provided. Anyway the best way is to test everything in real devices, as many as you can, even this very cheap layout we're dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

there is another way to do this instead of using `RelativeLayout` by using a third View , layout xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weigth="1"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

this way is better than using `RelativeLayout` and makes your layout smoother